# Últimos registros com base em um filtro

Tags: mysql, sql

Seguinte, preciso trazer em uma consulta os últimos registros que não foram alterados nos últimos 3 dias a partir de um `ID` especifico, ex.: `(id_chamado_status = '1')`.

Comment: isso em um campo select ?

Comment: isso mesmo (Victor)

Comment: existe algum campo do tipo date nesta mesma tabela, onde é armazenado a data que foi inserido o dado ?

Comment: @SkaylleBarreto vc tem algum campo que salva as datas de modificações?

Comment: Se possível, inclua nomes de tabelas, exemplo de select

Comment: @LucasSouza tenho uma tabela de histórico que  é alimentada por um INSERT caso seja feita qualquer alteração na aplicação.

Comment: @SkaylleBarreto acho que seria mais fácil vc criar uma campo "Date", só para controlar isso.. Pq com um campo só para controlar a data do update, vc cria uma trigger e o próprio banco já faz isso qd realizar o comando de update... Pq para vc varrer toda a tabela de histórico, pode ficar meio pesado a consulta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até onde sei não dá pra buscar registros "que não foram alterados" do banco. Se alguém alterar os registros ele simplesmente será alterado no banco (basta que a pessoa tenha permissão).

Se você quiser buscar a data de "3" dias atrás, no momento que inserir os seus dados deve salvar também a data de inserção, por exemplo, em uma coluna  de tipo `DATE` com um nome específico, aqui vou utilizar o nome `DT_REGISTRO` e aí buscar os dados:

```
SELECT * FROM <nome_sua_tabela> where DT_REGISTRO > 3
```

Comment: Esqueci de informar, mas tenho uma tabela que gera histórico caso esses registros seja alterados.

Comment: edite a pergunta e coloque as imagens da tabela e campos respectivos,e a tabela de registros alterados e campos respectivos

Comment: Você pode fazer um select na tabela original e trazer os registros que NÃO estão na segunda tabela("left join") e usar o where(dos tres dias) na primeira tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar primeiros ou últimos registro é necessário primeiro ordenar a consulta. Filtre o resultado e posteriormente "pegue" o retorno.

Obs. Para buscar os últimos registros, ordene a consulta de forma descendente.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2
FROM   TABELA
WHERE  FILTRO
ORDER BY CAMPO_DE_ORDENACAO DESC
LIMIT NUMERO_DE_REGISTROS
```

Fonte de pesquisa: [Documentação My SQL - Limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html)